# Dynamically Populating Xamarin C# ListView

Tags: c#, android, user-interface, listview, xamarin

I have a question about dynamically populating a ListView in Xamarin C#. So let's say I have an .axml file with a following ListView:

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_mylistview"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then, I have a .cs file which initializes this layout, so something like

```
public class MyInformationView : LinearLayout
    {
        private ListView _myListView;
        public MyInformationView(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {
            Initialize(context);
        }
        public MyInformationView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
            : base(context, attrs)
        {
            Initialize(context);
        }

        public MyInformationView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
            : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
            Initialize(context);
        }

......
```

So I have a `IEnumerable<string> SomeComponentCollection;` collection which I need to display in my ListView, how would I do that dynamically?

I see everyone on the internet is talking about ListView.ItemsSource property but I have no idea how they found this property since I get an error "listview does not have a definition of "ItemSource""

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read the docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/populating

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView.ItemsSource` is the method of the ListView in the Xamarin.Forms. In the xamarin.android, you need to use an adapter to populate it.

For the string date, you can use the ArrayAdapter and for some other complex data types, you may need to custom an adapter.

So you can try the following code:

```
 List<string> items = new List<string>(SomeComponentCollection);
 var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1, items);
 _myListView.Adapter = adapter;
```

You can also populate the listview in the activity.cs:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>(SomeComponentCollection);
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1, items);
ListView listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listview_mylistview);
listView.Adapter = adapter;
```